# Best practice to implement copy method in a class?

Tags: python, copy

What is the best practice to implement the `copy` method in a class?

Here is an example of my class:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, foo, bar=None):
        self.foo = foo
        if bar is not None:
            self.bar = bar
        else:
            self.bar = {'Hello': 'Ciao'}
```

I found a post of five years ago that suggests the following way:

```
import copy

def copy(self):
    return MyClass(copy.copy(self.foo), copy.copy(self.bar))
```

Is it still the only way to do it or are there other possibilities?

I need to create a copy of my object to avoid that a function changes the original object. The function is something like this:

```
def translate_and_print(my_class, dict={'Hello':'Ciao'}):
    temp = my_class # here I want to use the copy method: temp = my_class.copy()
    temp.foo = temp.bar[temp.foo]
    print(temp.foo)
```

The output of the following code is "Ciao", "Ciao" but should be "Ciao", "Hello"

```
mc = MyClass('Hello')
translate_and_print(mc)
print(mc.foo)
```

If I use the `copy()` method I have the error:

> AttributeError: 'MyClass' object has no attribute 'copy'

Comment: With regard to your updated comment, I can run `myobject = MyClass('foo')`, and then do `copy.copy(myobject)` without any issues. Can you provide a piece of code that reproduces your error?

Comment: Leaving the above comment in place for historical reasons. It seems your error is trying to call `my_class.copy()`, whereas you should be calling `copy.copy(my_class)`.

Comment: My post already includes it, specifically "you can simply call `copy.copy(myobject)`" in the end.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You got an `AttributeError`, I think that's because you just create a `copy` method, instead of that you need to create `__copy__` method.

```
import copy

class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
    def __copy__(self):
        return MyClass(self.name)
    def __deepcopy__(self, memo):
        return MyClass(copy.deepcopy(self.name, memo))
```

`__copy__` method for shallow copy and `__deepcopy__` for deep copy.

I hope you got the point, [Here is the link i follow](https://pymotw.com/2/copy/)

Comment: This might cause bugs in child classes due to implicit usage of `MyClass` initialiser. For example, copy of child class instance would become an instance of `MyClass`.

Answer (score 15):

You should implement the [`__copy__`](https://docs.python.org/library/copy.html) method, and possibly also `__deepcopy__`. The documentation states:

> In order for a class to define its own copy implementation, it can define special methods `__copy__()` and `__deepcopy__()`. The former is called to implement the shallow copy operation; no additional arguments are passed. The latter is called to implement the deep copy operation; it is passed one argument, the memo dictionary. If the `__deepcopy__()` implementation needs to make a deep copy of a component, it should call the `deepcopy()` function with the component as first argument and the memo dictionary as second argument.

With that said, unless you do some magic (e.g. C allocations, or calls to statefull C libraries), you should  not need to implement `__copy__` yourself, but python provides this for you for free, and you can simply call `copy.copy(myobject)`

Comment: Good thank you for the suggestion but this doesn't explain how to implement the method.

Comment: In your example, there is no reason to implement `__copy__`. If you have a use case where you actually use some low-level resources that require you to implement it, could you update your example and we can help out with that? In your example, the implementation you suggest adds nothing since python does that by default.

Comment: I edited the question.
The copy() method is not implemented in my class.

Comment: Great advice at end. I was trying create copy method when unnecessary.  `copy.copy` was magic bullet

Answer (score 5):

Follow implementation makes just copy, without calling the init() method.

```
class MyClass(BaseClass):
    def __init__(self, name):
        super().__init__()
        self.name = name

    def __copy__(self):
        obj = type(self).__new__(self.__class__)
        obj.__dict__.update(self.__dict__)
        return obj
```